# Changing the question based on new evidence or asking a new question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

### Context

I've asked a question on why some graph absorption pattern is shown on Earth. Based on information that Venus did not show this pattern. However, I could at the time not find a source that shows Venus does not show this pattern, so I thought it would be best to focus the question on asking why Earth shows this pattern (as I expected I would be able to derive the reason for that difference from that answer).

This question has been answered, and the answer, does not answer why it is shown on Earth but not on Venus, nor am I able to derive that from the answer. By now I have found the evidence that the pattern is not shown for Venus and included it in the question.

### Question

However, I am in doubt, whether it is better to change the question (back) to: "why is the pattern shown on Earth and not on Venus?" or whether it is better to keep the question on: "Why does Earth show this pattern?" and ask a new question with: "why is the pattern shown on Earth and not on Venus?"

For completeness [this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/43378/why-does-earth-have-a-dip-in-the-co2-absortion-spectrum-from-14-to-16-micron) is the question my doubt is about.

## Note

As pointed out by Connor Garcia♦, unchanged I think the question is not a best fit for Astronomy as it then is about Earth sciences. At the time of writing I did not realize this due to the XY-problem which is related to Astronomy. So if it is best to keep the question unchanged and ask a new question, I think I will vote to move the question to the Earth sciences site.

Comment: I was just asking the question if it was Earth Science or astronomy.   If it was clearly Earth Science, I would have just migrated it.  I think Peter Erwin's excellent answer and your edits to the question now make it clearly astronomy related!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Once answers begin to be posted** we need to work hard to restrain ourselves from changing the question in any way that interferes with the answers matching the question, and the usual etiquette is to check with answer authors before making big changes and to at least inform them even in the case of small changes of anything more than cosmetic impact. We have to accept that everything that happens in SE is imperfect, and sometimes just asking a new question linking back to the old one and refining/clarifying there is the best remedy.

Answer (score 2):

Including the extra source in the form of the image of Venus has led to an answer that answers the [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/303080), on why Earth has the pattern and Venus does not.

This makes the question astronomy related and implies no additional question is needed.

Comment: I've added a link to the Stack Exchange definition of the XY-problem. If that's not what you meant please feel free to link to the appropriate definition.